# Why I can not update a mat-option regarding to choosing mat-autocomplete select

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, lifecycle

I am trying to full my  array after choosing  opitonSelected. I want to send request after choosing one option to full the second  options. However my second (empty)  doesn't change. Still empty.

I tried to full the array with fake datas (['one','two','three']) but still same result.

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
<mat-label>Number</mat-label>
<input type="text"
       matInput
       [formControlName]= 'input'
       [matAutocomplete]="auto"
       [(ngModel)]="input.value">

<mat-autocomplete 
#auto="matAutocomplete" 
(optionSelected)="selectedCustomer($event.option)>

 <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions" [value]="option">
    {{option}}
  </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>

<div>
<mat-option *ngFor="let accountId of customerAccounts" 
[value]="accountId">
{{accountId}}
</mat-option>
</div>
```

When I cliked an option in , my dropdown's options are still empty.

```
selectedCustomer(option: MatOption) 
{
     const numbers = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
     this.customerAccounts = [...a];
}
```

Thank you for your help.

(Framework: Angular)

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproductible example with some part of your code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.